# When is it ok to meddle in the page lifecycle an ASP.NET MVC page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, overriding, page-lifecycle

It seems that ASP.NET MVC just runs on top of ASP.NET WebForms.  System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage in ASP.NET MVC inherits from System.Web.UI.Page which includes page lifecycle methods like OnRender and friends.

I have seen a couple of comments around the web to the effect that you should resist the urge to override these methods AT ALL COSTS!.  Of course, this means that I find myself resisting the urge to do just that.

Is there really that much wrong with something like the following?

```
public class SslPage : ViewPage
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure we are using SSL
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

        if(url.StartsWith("http:"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https" + url.Remove(0, 4),false);
        }

        // Back to our regularly scheduled programming...
        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
}
```

One could debate the purity of putting that in a "View" but it seems plenty expedient.

How dangerous/blasphemous is it to override these methods?  When might it make sense?

Comment: MVC does not run on WebForms. They both run on ASP.NET, but are otherwise unrelated. There isn't really a page lifecycle in MVC. The appropriate place for enforcing https is probably a filter or in a base controller.

Comment: Ryan's comment is technically incorrect. WebForms is built into System.Web. You can take any ASP.NET MVC app and add runat='server' and the whole page lifecycle reveals itself in all it's glory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with what you describe is that the view is only rendered once the controller decides *which* view to render. It may seem surprising at first, but by the time your `OnPreInit` method is called, all of the logic of the controller has *already* executed.

The correct place to put this, as @Ryan says, is in a filter or a base controller.

Comment: Dean, thank you for clearing up my very silly mistake.  I was adding MVC to an existing WebForms site and my mind was clearly in a request=page mode.  Of course, you are right that a view (page) is only created at the request of the controller (much too late for what I was doing).